# ffmpeg Private Stream error or bug

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am stuck with an error `muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading`.

Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.idx -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s dvbsub -metadata:s:s:0 language=ara OUTPUT.ts
```

I am getting this error with all new versions of ffmpeg but not from version `N-94334-gab4795a085 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716`

What is the issue here exactly? don't know if something wrong with the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug or error. I added a message to warn users when a stream to be muxed is not in the recognized list. However, that list is incomplete, so you're getting that message for DVB subtitles. The resulting file should have functional subtitles just like earlier.

I'll add the DVB text streams to the list.

Comment: Seems to me that this message should be suppressed if I am manually mapping data streams, e.g. `-map 0:d`.

Comment: Data streams are always manually mapped. Presumably the purpose of muxing a stream is to read it later. The warning tells you that it may not be possible using ffmpeg.